# Libgdx: How to move objects on X axis without overlapping?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a rectangle array holding multiple objects, moving back and forth on X axis.

```
Iterator<Rectangle> iter = array.iterator();

while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
    Rectangle obj = iter.next();
    array.get(i).x += speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() ;

    if (obj.x + obj.width > 800 || obj.x < 0) {
        speed = -speed;
    }
}
```

When the speed gets bigger, you'll start noticing the first object in the array overlapping with the other objects and pushing them apart. How to fix that?

Basically each object has

```
Rectangle obj = new Rectangle();
obj.x = xpos;
obj.y = ypos;
obj.width = width;
obj.height = height;
xpos += width + 4;
```

And has a texture, image, a sqaure, a rectange, a triangle... And each object is generated at an X position `xpos` different than the other. All they do is keep moving on the X axis, from x=0 till 800 and back.

What happens is that when the first object gets to 0, it tries to increase its speed again and overlapping with other objects, and then time after time, all objects keep overlapping and get further apart from each other. I want the distance between the objects to stay constant at any speed.

Comment: Your code snippets are hard to understand and so is the question text. Please try to be clear in what you are trying to achieve and post the important parts of the code so we don't have to guess what things are.

Comment: @p.streef better now?

Comment: Not really. First off, your code sample would not compile since you reuse the name "array" second off. you talk like we know what every object you use is. but we still have to guess. What is a rectangle? what is inside the array? what is obj? As a sidenote. this has nothing to do with iOS or android so those tags don't belong..

Comment: @p.streef thank you for your comments, better now?

Comment: It is getting better, yes. But frankly, it is still quite unclear what you want to achieve. If you say collide I expect some actual physics collision. If you mean overlap then say so. If you don't want the positions to differ between objects then why do you treat them as different objects? Perhaps the solution lies in changing the direction for all objects at the same time while mirroring their position? Also if it is important to keep a constant pace, you could do an update in a seperate thread/timer with a constant update speed. This way you have more control at high speeds.

Comment: @p.streef I replaced collide with overlap. `hy do you treat them as different objects? `  I tried to use `obj.x += speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() ;` instead of `array.get(i).x += speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() ;` I had no luck, do you suggest i generate 1 object instead of many?

Comment: @p.streef `lso if it is important to keep a constant pace, you could do an update in a seperate thread/timer with a constant update speed. This way you have more control at high speeds` ahhh I'll try that

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do from your code, but you almost certainly don't want to complicate it with multithreading. Right now, your for loop cycles through all objects, moving them a certain amount, but immediately changes the direction partway through the loop if any object hits the edge of the screen. This might happen multiple times during the loop, so various different objects will have different directions of movement. I'm just guessing, but you want each object to have its own speed and bounce off the side of the screen? Then you need a separate speed variable for each rect.

Comment: @Tenfour04 your guess is 100% correct and thats exactly what im trying to solve. I want all objects to have the same speed and when one of them reaches the edge they should all move at the oposite direction at the same time so that they maintain the distance between each other always. the distance between all objects must stay fixed, I dont want an object to start turning and hit another object

Comment: So the whole group is locked together and only the ones on the two ends bounce?

Comment: @Tenfour04 exactly, the first and last elements of arrayList are the ones which bounce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've commented, the questions appears to be "How can I make all these blocks move together, bouncing from one edge to another". The issue being that you're getting bouncing, but they stop acting as a group.

---

Firstly, if you want to treat them as a group - the simplest way is to consider them as one large bounding box containing lots of smaller (inconsequential) objects. Moving that as a single object from side to side will give you the behaviour you need.

---

That aside, the direct answer to your question is **"you're changing the direction mid-way through iteration"**. So in any single tick, some objects have moved left and some have moved right - meaning they stop acting as a group.

How you organise it is up to you, but this is the basic idea you need:

```
// assume "speedForThisFrame" is a float defined outside this function
float speedForNextFrame = speedForThisFrame
// iterate through however you want
Iterator<Rectangle> iter = array.iterator();
while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
    Rectangle obj = iter.next();
    obj.x += speedForThisFrame * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() ;

    // if it's moved out of bounds, we will change direction NEXT fame
    if (obj.x + obj.width > 800 || obj.x < 0) {
        speedForNextFrame = -speedForThisFrame;
    }
}
// now that all movement has finished, we update the speed
speedForThisFrame = speedForNextFrame
```

The key thing is everything must move by the same amount, in the same direction, every frame. Changing the speed mid-update will cause them to act independently.

Note, you will still have issues when your group is larger than the bounds - or when they go over the bounds in one frame and don't fully get back the next frame. These are separate issues though and can be asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that, caused by variations in Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), the rectangles exceed your 0/800 borders by different distances.

An example:
First step:

```
Rect #1 x=790
Rect #2 x=780
Speed=100, DeltaTime=0.11 => DeltaX=11
```

After this step, Rect#1 would be at 801, Rect#2 at 791, their distance is 10.

Next step:

```
DeltaTime=0.12 => DeltaX=12
```

After this step, Rect#1 is at 789, Rect#2 at 803, their distance is 14.

Your rectangles vary their distance because they travel different distances. A possible solution would be to really bounce at the borders. So you should not only invert the speed but also take the distance a rectangle exceeded the border and let it travel this distance in the opposite direction:

So Rect#1 at 790, moving 11 pixels rightwards, should not be at 801 in the end of the step but at 799 (moving 10 pixels to the right and one to the left).

Comment: It's not the answer to the question asked - but this is the solution to another problem people seeing this will likely come across straight after (where items will go over the boundary and get "stuck" over/shake rapidly).

Comment: yes this helps a lot, but I dont know how to implement the solution proposed